Loosing ATAC metadata when merging with RNA - unable to find out why
I am using my sc-RNA Seurat object to predict cell identity of my sc-ATAC, and then I want to merge both objects to project onto one UMAP. When I visualize the combined object (coembed) using DimPlot, I only see RNA cells. Everything in the metadata leads me to believe the ATAC cells are there, but for some reason they are not showing up for me.
Any help is GREATLY appreciated! I'll annotate my code below.

library(Seurat)
library(Signac)
library(qs)
atac_CJ <- readRDS("file_path.rds")
rna_CJ <- qread("file_path.qs")

atac_CJ <- RunTFIDF(atac_CJ)
atac_CJ <- FindTopFeatures(atac_CJ, min.cutoff = 'q0')
atac_CJ <- RunSVD(atac_CJ, reduction.name = 'lsi', reduction.key = 'LSI_')

atac_CJ$experiment <- "ATAC"
rna_CJ$experiment <- "RNA"

common_features <- intersect(rownames(rna_CJ), rownames(atac_CJ[["GeneActivity"]]))  
# removing custom transgenes from prediction
custom_genes <- c("rna_EGFP", "rna_KMT2B-T-HA-Flag", "rna_Myc-d90-bCatenin", "rna_Glu-Glu-NRAS-V12G") 
filtered_features <- setdiff(common_features, intersect(common_features, custom_genes))

transfer.anchors <- FindTransferAnchors(
  reference = rna_CJ,
  query = atac_CJ,
  features = filtered_features,
  reference.assay = "RNA",
  query.assay = "GeneActivity",
  reduction = "cca",
  verbose = TRUE
)

predicted.labels <- TransferData(
  anchorset = transfer.anchors, 
  refdata = rna_CJ$manual_ident, 
  weight.reduction = atac_CJ[["lsi"]],
  dims = 2:20
)

atac_CJ <- AddMetaData(object = atac_CJ, metadata = predicted.labels)
DefaultAssay(rna_CJ) <- "RNA"
DefaultAssay(atac_CJ) <- "GeneActivity"

# Following Seurat's coembed pipeline

coembed <- merge(x = rna_CJ, y = atac_CJ)
coembed <- FindVariableFeatures(coembed, features = common_features)
coembed <- ScaleData(coembed, features = common_features, do.scale = FALSE)
coembed <- RunPCA(coembed, features = common_features, verbose = FALSE)
coembed <- RunUMAP(coembed, dims = 1:30)
DimPlot(coembed, group.by = c("manual_ident", "celltype") 
# manual_ident is RNA, celltype is ATAC
# This is where I cannot figure out why ATAC cells are not present 
umap_cells <- colnames(coembed@reductions$umap@cell.embeddings)
table(umap_cells %in% rownames(coembed@meta.data[coembed$experiment == "ATAC", ]))
# FALSE 
#   2
# This is where I believe I am loosing cells, but I do not know why
# table(coembed$experiment) shows expected number of RNA and ATAC cells

                                                


